# How to create Bash script to complete my email address?

Tags: bash, auto-completion

I am trying to write a bash script to auto-complete my email address. So my goal is whenever I type `foo` in terminal and hit `tab` it completes it with `foo.bar@gmail.com`.

So far I read these links: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/how-to-specify-a-custom-autocomplete-for-specific-commands?newreg=8f29593bf62a4dcb92c96c33219271fd
https://debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2

But I couldn't achieve as both of them make auto-complete like `foo [tab]`.
I'm sorry if I couldn't  explain my question well but I don't want that space after `foo`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, auto-completion is program in-depended. When you type `command1 foo` it looks specifically for command1's completion scripts and for `command2 foo` it looks for command2's completion scripts.

If you want your Email address a command it self and not an argument then:

```
$ touch ~/.local/bin/pouria@gmail.com
$ chmod +x ~/.local/bin/pouria@gmail.com
```

Make sure `~/.local/bin/` is in your PATH. Now:

```
pou[tab]
```

Completes it.

Another cool trick is to use aliases. Add a new alias like this:

```
alias 1='mymail@mail.com'
```

Now type `1` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>. Done.

Comment: That's correct. My solution was wrong from the beginning. Also, nice hack! Thanks.

Comment: I've added another cool trick. Check it out you might like it. and you're welcome ;)